# Update to NSManagedObject causes NSFetchedResultsController delete

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobject

I have quite a frustrating problem that I have been struggling with for quite some time.

To provide some context and detail I have an iOS UISplitViewController application - standard master / detail stuff. The master view is a UITableView backed with an NSFetchedResultsController (which loads NSManagedObjects from a SQLite data store).

What seems to be happening is that any update within the details view (which can routinely cause updates to the 'master records' and are flushed to NSManagedObject's and ultimately the SQL data store) causes a DELETE operation on the NSFetchedResultsController.

I assume that this is because the write to the NSManagedObject property(s) are causing a fault of some kind, which in turn causes the NSFetchedResultsController to expunge it from it's cached result set. The end result is that records go 'missing' from the master view (e.g.: UITableCellView's are removed from the master UITableView).

The issue is that I don't want this to happen and I have no idea how to stop it...

Has anyone experienced this issue before and could possibly provide some guidance?

Thanks in advance,
Ben

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but I figured out the solution to a similar problem I was having.  I was sorting the objects in my Core Data-backed UITableView by the first letter of the name of each object.  In whatever tutorial I read, it told me to put a transient property 'NameInitial' in the NSManagedObject subclass that I would populate with the first letter of the name of that object.  I then used that property as my sectionNameKeyPath to sort the objects into the proper sections in my UITableView.

I had a button on each cell that updated a property of the object associated with that cell, and I properly received NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate messages in my didChangeObject delegate function.  HOWEVER, sometimes, cells would get deleted and I would receive the NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete message for no apparent reason.

Then I noticed that the cells that were getting deleted had (null) as the NameInitial property for their associated object.  I had forgotten that the transient NameInitial is only stored in memory, and so is not necessarily maintained all the time.  Once I manually repopulated the NameInitial property each time I updated a cell, the deleting stopped.  So if you are using a transient property to help sort/section your UITableView, this might be your problem.

Hope this helps, and good luck!
-Rick